# SVG overflow visible renders marker in an inconsistent manner in Windows 10 Chrome/Edge

Tags: google-chrome, svg, overflow

When the width of the `<svg>` tag is less than the `<marker>` inside and if the overflow property is set to visible, the resulting image has inconsistent width only in Windows 10 Chrome/Edge. It works fine in Windows 10 Firefox and it works fine on all browsers in Mac.

1. No width is set on `<svg>`

[image]

2. When width is 1px (Notice how it is wide)

[image]

3. When width is 2px (Normal size)

[image]

You can try this codepen with different widths in different browsers.

https://codepen.io/anandpopat9/pen/KKgVOGa?editors=1010

Would really appreciate if someone can give some insight into this.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you add width, height and viewbox to the svg tag? Like `<svg style="overflow: visible" viewBox="0 0 1 50" width="1" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> .... </svg>`

Comment: Still the same behavior!

Comment: It works fine for me in Edge version 87.0.664.55.  But I notice I get the stretching/squashing effect if I change the zoom.  Check your zoom level.

Comment: Even with Edge version 87.0.664.55, I am noticing the same effect. I am running it on Windows 10 v2004 19041.630